# Multiple checkbox values to spring controller

Tags: java, ajax, spring-boot, thymeleaf

In my project using these technologies. SpringBoot, Thymeleaf, Ajax. I have a situation where after clicking a button it will call a controller1 by ajax call and get the response. I am populating this response as a table in which the first column as a checkbox and the remaining are normal columns. Here user can select any check boxes and click submit button and it will go to a different controller2 in a different project. How can I pass the selected check box values to controller2.

```
From html page onClick of radio buttom calling the below ajax call method and got response from controller1 in a different project amd populated in a table contains check boxe in each row.
```

\EntryScreen.html
    -

function generateHoldings() {
    var acctNo = $("#account").val().trim();
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/holdingsView?account="+encodeURIComponent(acctNo)

```
     if (acctNo !== '' && acctNo !== null) {
        var jqxhr = $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url : url,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            dstsType: 'JSON'
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: 'text/plain'
        });
        jqxhr.done(function(data, status, jqxhr)) {

        }
    }
```

}

Here user can select any check boxes and click submit button and it will go to a different controller2 in a different project. How can I pass the selected check box values to controller2.

Comment: without any code for your current setup, we can't really help you

Answer (score 0):

The info that you have provided, is not enough to answer correctly. still what I have understood based on that I have written below thing.
You have to dynamically build(using jquery) the html table after receiving the response from first controller. how many rows and column will be there, it will be depended on response only. while the table dynamically being built you have to write code in jquery to set unique ID for each selection box. now when you will invoke another ajax query for second controller and that time you need to pass those values.